# What is the reward for ranking up?

Tags: chivalry-medieval-warfare

In Chivalry: Medieval Warfare, you can rank up by getting kills. What is the point of ranking up? IS it just bragging, or do you get bonuses (Ex. more damage, helmets, etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rank is purely cosmetic and do not offer any benefits gameplay-wise. The helmets released so far are dependent on weapon unlocks.

Comment: Reaching higher levels unlocks new weapons, not purely cosmetic.